# Add an array by selecting checkbox with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I faced with a small problem adding proper data to my submit form. All fileds for this form come dynamically from http request, one of this fields is categories, values for this field come dynamically from another http request, with help of ng-repeat I render values in my form. Values have an ids and names. I need to send in my form the array of ids of categories looks like `categories: [1,4,5,7]`, where numbers are id of selected categories. The problem is my array looks like `categories: [1: true, 5, true ]` what is totally wrong. This is [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Hv4P81muef7dldM0sqc?p=preview) with my problem. I suppose something wrong with my ng-model, but cannot find what exactly. So could anybody tell me what I am missing?

code

```
     $scope.category = [
    {"id":5,"name":"Data Quality"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Documentation"},
    {"id":4,"name":"Drug Supply"},
    {"id":8,"name":"Enrollment"},
    {"id":3,"name":"Patient Safety"},
    {"id":7,"name":"Randomization"},
    {"id":9,"name":"Site Performance"},
    {"id":1,"name":"Study Conduct"},
    {"id":6,"name":"Technology Related"}
    ]

    $scope.sendData = {}

    $scope.vmodel = angular.copy($scope.sendData);

 $scope.onSubmit = function (event) {
                if (event.id == null || event.id == 0) {
                    console.log(event)
                }
            };
```

html

```
 <div class="form-check-inline" ng-repeat="cat in category">
      <label class="form-check-label col-xs-4 no-padding" for="categories" ng-true-value="'{{cat.name}}'" ng-false-value="''">
                        {{ cat.name }}
                  <input type="checkbox" 
                  class="form-check-input col-xs-2"
                  id="categories" 
                  ng-model="vmodel.categories[cat.id]" />
      </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your output (vmodel.categories) looks like `{"5":true,"7":true,"8":true,"9":true}`, right? And you're looking for [5, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: @user3080953 that's correct

Comment: heres a fixed fork : [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/JmIKhSstF3ScCGa6nbev?p=preview)

Comment: @KaushalNiraula thank you a lot!! It works perfect

Comment: can you mark it as complete?

Comment: i added the answer in answer section, just mark it as answer. Click the checkmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label class="form-check-label col-xs-4 no-padding" for="categories" ng-true-value="'{{cat.name}}'" ng-false-value="''">
            {{ cat.name }}
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input col-xs-2"  ng-click="add(cat.id)" id="categories" />
          </label>


$scope.sendData = {
    categories: []
  }

  $scope.add = function(id) {
    if ($scope.sendData['categories'].indexOf(id) == -1) {
      $scope.sendData.categories.push(id);
    } else {
      $scope.sendData.categories.splice($scope.sendData['categories'].indexOf(id), 1);

    }
    console.log($scope.sendData);



  }

  $scope.onSubmit = function(event) {

    console.log($scope.sendData)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your input is {"5":true,"7":true,"8":true,"9":true}. I see two options:

1) Transform the object:

```
$scope.$watch('vmodel.categories', function(val) { 
  if (val) 
    $scope.selected = Object.keys(val)
    console.log($scope.selected)  // output is $scope.selected
}, true)
```

2) Change the way you listen for events

```
<!-- html --> 
<input type='checkbox' ng-click='toggle(cat)' />


// js 
$scope.selected = [] 
$scope.toggle = function(cat) {
  if ($scope.vmodel.categories[cat]) 
    $scope.selected.push(cat) 
  else 
    $scope.selected.remove(cat) // pretend this function exists in js
}
```